# Headers being passed in as null?

Tags: angular, get, http-headers

I'm creating a web service to host my API on using Angular. I'm sending a GET request but I keep getting the following error:

```js
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

When I checked my backend it was because the headers are being passed in as null.

I have a cross origin extension on Chrome. I used postman to check if the backend was working and the headers were passing fine. It's my Angular application that's causing the null headers. I have the following method:

```js
get_url(){
  let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

  headers.append('fsreqid','test');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer 4Agl9Gd75LHEvOmXqKoZh4oUlxjqZs4Tg6dF8vcx7qymwjE8ni5gT8');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  return this.http
    .get(this.url, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      observe: 'response' 
      ResponseType: 'json'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try using

```
headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('fsreqid','test');
headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer 4Agl9Gd75LHEvOmXqKoZh4oUlxjqZs4Tg6dF8vcx7qymwjE8ni5gT8');
headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

append() doesn't modify input headers, so you have to reassign headers:

```
 let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

 headers = headers.append('fsreqid','test');
 headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer 4Agl9Gd75LHEvOmXqKoZh4oUlxjqZs4Tg6dF8vcx7qymwjE8ni5gT8');
 headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

or setup all appends in constructor:

```
  let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
        .append('fsreqid','test')
        .append('Authorization', 'Bearer 4Agl9Gd75LHEvOmXqKoZh4oUlxjqZs4Tg6dF8vcx7qymwjE8ni5gT8')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. <-getting this error

Comment: That's the whole new problem. Your server don't accept request from localhost. To learn more about this problem, please visit e.q.: https://medium.com/@electra_chong/what-is-cors-what-is-it-used-for-308cafa4df1a